# How I can properly blend a texture in top of a color with transparency?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So basically I have the following shader where I mix the texture with a color that has transparency

```
void main()
{
  vec4 backgroundColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 0.2);
  fragColor = texture(uTexture, texturePosition);
  fragColor = mix(backgroundColor, fragColor, fragColor.w);
}
```

The result of this looks okay at a first glance:

[image]

The background red color is transparent and allows to see what is behind and in top of that I get this transparent texture.

The issue is that the alpha of the texture, in this case the "Resume Game" text has alpha in the border of each letter, which looks like this when the mix in the shader is not applied

[image]

But after the mix is applied it looks like the transparency in the borders of the letters is lost:

[image]

What will be the proper way to blend a texture in top of a color?